# Associativity of the tensor product of dendroidal sets

Tags: category-theory, trees, simplicial-stuff, operads

For any smal category $A$, I shall write $\widehat A$ for the category $[A^{\text op}, \mathbf{Set}]$ of presheaves on $A$, and $y_A\colon A \to \widehat A$ for the Yoneda embedding relative to $A$.

I denote by $\Delta$ the category of [simplices](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex+category), by $\Omega$ the category of [symmetric dendroids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dendroidal+set#Trees) (or symmetric finite rooted trees) and by $\mathbf{Oper}$ the category of [symmetric operads](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+operad). The last two categories were introduced by I. Moerdijk and I. Weiss in [WeissPhD](http://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/22859) and [MW07](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701293); in the same articles they introduced the notion of Boardman-Vogt tensor product of operads $\otimes_{\text BV}\colon\mathbf{Oper}\times\mathbf{Oper}\to\mathbf{Oper}$, which endows the category of small operads with a symmetric closed monoidal structure.

As $\mathbf{Oper}$ is a Bénabou cosmos with the Boardman-Vogt tensor product, we can define a pair of adjoint functors $\tau_d\dashv N_d$ with the nerve-realization paradigm (using the fact the $\mathbf{Oper}$ is cocomplete) and a tensor product of dendroidal sets (*i.e.* presheaves on $\Omega$) $\otimes \colon\widehat \Omega\times \widehat\Omega\to \widehat\Omega$ defined as the left Kan extension of $N_d(-\otimes -)\colon \Omega\times \Omega\to \widehat\Omega$ along $y_\Omega$.

In §3.5 of the article [HHM15](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3658v3.pdf) it is stated that the category of dendroidal sets $\widehat \Omega$ is *weakly enriched* over the cartesian closed category of simplical sets $\widehat \Delta$.

Thanks to the nerve-realization paradigm $\tau_d\dashv N_d$ (for the dendroidal-operadic case), it is enough to prove that there exists a natural isomorphism

$$
\varphi \colon y_\Delta\!\cdot\otimes(y_\Delta\!\cdot\otimes\, y_\Omega\cdot) \to N_d\bigl(\,\cdot\otimes_{\text BV}(\,\cdot\otimes_{\text BV}\cdot\,)\bigr):\Delta\times (\Delta\times \Omega) \to \widehat\Omega
$$
and hence the weak enrichement follows by astract non-sense and the associativity of the Boardman-Vogt tensor product.

More generally, fixed an object $R$ of $\Omega$, the functor $\Omega^R\otimes\cdot\,\colon \widehat\Omega \to \widehat\Omega$ can be express as the left Kan extension of $N_d\circ R\otimes_{\text BV}\cdot$ along $y_\Omega$. Thus

$$
\bigl( \Delta^m\otimes (\Delta^n \otimes \Omega^T)\bigr)_S
\cong \int^R \widehat \Omega(\Omega^R, \Delta^n \otimes \Omega^T)\times N_d([m]\otimes_{\text BV} R)_S\\
\phantom{AALA\bigl( \Omega^R\otimes (\Omega^S \otimes \Omega^T)\bigr)_Q}\cong \int^R \mathbf{Oper}(R, [n]\otimes_{\text BV} T) \times \mathbf{Oper}(S, [m]\otimes_{\text BV} R)\\
$$
for any $[m], [n]$ in $\Delta$, $T$ in $\text{Ob}\Omega$, and where we have denoted by $\Omega^T$  the presheaf $y_\Omega T$ on $\Omega$. Amazingly enough,

$$
\int^{R\in \Omega} \mathbf{Oper}(R, [n]\otimes_{\text BV} T) \times \mathbf{Oper}(S, [m]\otimes_{\text BV} R) \cong \int^{\mathcal P \in \mathbf{Oper}} \mathbf{Oper}(\mathcal P, [n]\otimes_{\text BV} T) \times \mathbf{Oper}(S, [m]\otimes_{\text BV} \mathcal P)
$$
where the last term is exaclty the coend form ([Yoneda expansion](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma#every_presheaf_is_a_colimit_of_representables)) of the functor $N_d([m]\otimes_{\text BV}\cdot\,)_S\colon \mathbf{Oper} \to \mathbf{Set}$ evaluated in $[n]\otimes_{\text BV} T$.

Using the adjunction $\tau_d\dashv N_d$ and the fact that $\tau_d$ distributes over the tensor product of dendroidal sets, it is possible to get then a natural transformation
$$
 \alpha\colon (y_\Delta\cdot\times y_\Delta\cdot\,)\otimes y_\Omega\cdot \to y_\Delta\cdot\otimes (y_\Delta\cdot\otimes y_\Omega\cdot\,) : \Delta \times \Delta \times \Omega \to \widehat\Omega\ .
$$

**Question 1.** What is an example of a pair of operads $\mathcal{P, Q}$ in $\text{Ob}\mathbf{Oper}$ such that $N_d(\mathcal P\otimes_{\text BV}\mathcal Q)$ is *not* isomorphic to $N_d(\mathcal P) \otimes N_d(\mathcal Q)$, *i.e.* for which the nerve does not distribute over the Boardman-Vogt tensor product?

It is stated in §3.5 of [HHM15](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3658v3.pdf) that the category $\widehat\Omega$ of dendroidal sets is not a monoidal category with the tensor product, as the associativity fails. Indeed, they prove a *weak* associativity for representable presheaves, as I worked out above, and then it is stated that extending by colimits to all triple of presheaves on $\Omega$ *that* particular natural isomorphism between triple of representable presheaves, then the comparison morphism is not an isomorphism in general.

**Question 2.** What is an example of a triple of presheaves $X, Y, Z$ on $\Omega$ such that the comparison morphism built in [HHM15](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3658v3.pdf) is not an isomorphism? An example for which $X, Y$ are actually presheaves on $\Delta$ would be appreciated even more.

**Question 3.** Why cannot exist any other *associator* $\alpha$ (natural isomorphism for the associativity) making $(\widehat \Omega, \otimes, \alpha, \lambda, \rho, \underline{hom}_\Omega)$ a closed symmetric monoidal category?

For any presheaves $X, Y$ on $\Omega$ and any object $T$ of $\Omega$, we define $\underline{hom}_\Omega(X, Y)_T = \widehat\Omega(\Omega^T\otimes X, Y)$.

Comment: I assume you wrote the right coend. Then the [ninja Yoneda lemma](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma) tells you that 
$$ (\Delta^m\otimes (\Delta^n\otimes \Omega^T))_R \cong \mathbf{Opd}(R, [m]\otimes ([n]\otimes T))$$
which is, I think, something less scary.

Comment: I think it all boils down in defining us the functor $N_d$: if it sends $\mathcal C$ to the presheaf $R\mapsto \mathbf{Opd}(R, \mathcal C)$, I think we are done!

Comment: Right! I improved the questions based on this remark.

Comment: I copied the same thread [on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198051/tensor-product-of-dendroidal-sets-counter-examples), as well.

Comment: A complete and nice answer by G. Heuts can be found [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/198361/42137).